# Wordpress Admin is displaying Not Available

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

[image: Not Available]

I am trying to go to wp-admin, but after I login I keep seeing this. I already tried renaming plugin but still I can't login to wp-admin.

Comment: Change current theme folder name from ftp.

Comment: I can't add an answer (low reputation for now), so I'll leave a comment here: in my case it was `All-in-One WP Security and Firewall` that prevent the access to the WP Admin with the same message. I've prefixed the `wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall` with an underscore (`_all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall`) and I could get access to the WP Admin again. Don't forget to enable the plugin again once you've done your changes :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are different reasons why this can happen. In your case I think it may be a security plugin that has changed the deafult login URL to something else.

When I go to http://www.philenglish.com.cn/wp-login.php I get a 404 error, which is something such plugins also do: they make the default login URLs unavailable in an attempt to make your site more secure.

If you don't know what the login URL is changed to, I would first disable any security plugins installed on the site. You mention you've already tried disabling plugins, but looking at your site's source code, I can see there are still plugins active. So I would double-check you've really disabled your plugins.

An easy way would be to connect to your site through FTP and navigate to your plugins folder. Normally you would find this here:

```
wp-content > plugins
```

Your can either look in your plugins folder and find the plugin that might cause this issue. And then disable it by temporarily renaming the folder.

Or you can disable all plugins at once by temporarily renaming the whole plugins folder.

As an aside: this is the quickest way to disable plugins, but you may lose some settings when you reactivate your plugins. You can also [quickly disable all plugins through phpmyadmin while retaining options](https://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/).

I hope this helps you. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Do the following steps one by one and so you can check what causing you this error ...

1) Rename .htaccess file

2) rename theme folder

3) rename pluginn folder

Please upvote my answer ....

Comment: This is a very vague response. Just renaming core folders alone will certainly not solve this problem, it will just cause other kind of problems.

Comment: Hi Maricio, The steps which i have mentioned are to be done by step by step (single step at a time - so if you rename the .htaccess file then undo or change other steps to WordPress original folder names.) so we can identify whether any theme ot plugin causing the problem or an .htaccess file causing it. for example after renaming plugin folder your if your website is working fine then you can find the plugin and disable or remove (unless you are a developer to correct the errors in plugin). anyways thanks for the downvote without asking for an explanation.

Comment: Downvotes exist for a reason: it's for answers that confuse or do not explain enough. This is the case here. The answer lacks a lot of context and can indeed cause other kinds of issues. Also, “Please upvote my answer” is not useful at all.